# What are the main steps to prepare and promote my fiction novel?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, marketing

I completed a draft of a fiction book that several friends have read and enjoyed. Assuming I can raise the money on Kickstarter, what services should I employ to maximize success of the book? I plan on releasing it as an eBook and in paperback.

Obviously I need the following:

1. Professional content editing
2. Professional cover and artwork design
3. Professional self-publication (like iUniverse and Kindle)
4. Professional marketing and promotion

What else should I add to this list?

Comment: Maybe quotes from authors of similar works about your book for the cover. If you ask them really nicely there are a few here and there who will help out like that.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that will make your book successful:

## 1

What you need first and foremost is readers. So you need to build a **[platform](https://www.google.com/search?q=platform%20marketing)**. See the books by Michael Hyatt, Jeff Walker, Guy Kawasaki, and others* on the subject.

In short, what you need to do is have a website, start to blog, connect through Twitter, and generally brand yourself and network with prospective readers through social media. Ideally you would have already done all that while you were writing your book, so that now that it is finished you could simply mail out a newsletter or post a Tweet with a link to the finished product.

## 2

The second most important thing is that you quickly write your next book. Books sell each other, and a happy reader not finding another book by the same author is one reader lost.

All bestselling authors have a score of books out there. So sit down and start on the next novel and publish that within six months to a year. And then the next.

Obviously 1 and 2 take away time and energy from each other, which is why successful authors either have a publisher who takes care of marketing, a husband who takes care of marketing, or pay someone to take care of marketing. There are *very* few successful authors who do all of this alone, and most can only do it alone on the basis of past success from publisher-published books.

---

* All these books contain about one page worth of useful advice, and this advice can be found freely on the web, so don't buy the books. I'm just naming these authors so you know who the popular authorities are and were to start googling.

Comment: Agreed, especially #2. I would like to add that

Comment: Stupid timeout...I would like to add that you should seek online forums that discuss topics that come up in your book. DO NOT mention that you have a book that touches on the subject until you've garnered some reputation in that online community. This could take months, so get started now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maximize the success of your book, seek professional publication. Being successful with self publishing is like being successful playing the lottery. Even those who win small prizes now and then pay out more than they take in, and the real jackpots are incredibly rare.

But is you actually manage to raise money for self publishing on Kickstarter, do let us know, because, frankly, I assume that is impossible.